# I recently installed google's recaptcha, but they am still receiving spam. Any ideas why?

Tags: recaptcha

I recently installed Google's recaptcha on a client's site, on 2 of their web forms for which they'd been receiving spam submissions.

However, even after installing, the client is still receiving frequent spam submissions on both forms.

The submissions are strings of apparently random letters, a la the following:

- First Name: Lvyhjlgy
- Last Name: Lvyhjlgy
- Company Name: QkKVGvjWSXXv
- Street Address: upPmnNKUcwtwrojw
- Street Address2: WOALpPHKQPEkRpDYg
- City: rFlWMPHNoxNRJTr

My working hypothesis right now is that the issue has something to do with displaying the public sitekey in the div used for the captcha, copy and pasted from google's recaptcha admin:

`<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"></div>`

But am not sure at all that that's relevant.

Does anyone have any insight into why I'm still receiving spam and what I could do to prevent this?

Thanks!

Comment: We don't have anywhere near enough information to tell you what's happening. There are tons of possibilities, such as the possibility that they're just solving the captchas.

Comment: Ay! sorry about that. thanks for letting me know. What info would help you to tell what's happening?